# follow an alias link to a directory, using zsh and ohmyzsh

Tags: command-line, alias

Is it possible to follow an alias link in Terminal using zsh and ohmyzsh?

My Terminal states: 'zsh: permission denied:' or 'cd: not a directory:' .

The alias is of course a little file and not a directory.
But in that file there is a pointer to the actual position.
I want to switch directories in a script using the alias link.

Comment: Can you use symbolic links rather than aliases?

Answer (score 2):

Aliases are a Finder thing, Unix shells don't know how to make use of them.

- Use symlinks instead of aliases
- Use tools like `alisma` (downloadable from https://eclecticlight.co/taccy-signet-precize-alifix-utiutility-alisma/, scroll down for the entry) which make the content/target of a Finder alias accessible in Unix shells.